# Enable Gitlab Docker prometheus

Tags: docker, gitlab, prometheus

I'm running Gitlab-Docker but I'm unable to connect to http://localhost:9090 where Prometheus is supposed to be.
These are my commands on Ubuntu ARM64:

```
docker run \
  --detach \
  --restart always \
  --name gitlab-ce \
  --privileged \
  --memory 4096M \
  --publish 22:22 \
  --publish 80:80 \
  --publish 443:443 \
  --env GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG=" \
    external_url 'http://localhost';
    node_exporter['enable'] = true;
    grafana['enable'] = true;
    nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true; "\
  --volume /srv/gitlab-ce/conf:/etc/gitlab:z \
  --volume /srv/gitlab-ce/logs:/var/log/gitlab:z \
  --volume /srv/gitlab-ce/data:/var/opt/gitlab:z \
  yrzr/gitlab-ce-arm64v8:latest
```

The weird thing is that I can have access to Grafana on http://localhost/-/grafana and get some metrics, but I don't have access to http://localhost/-/metrics endpoint either. If I add: `node_exporter['enable'] = true` to GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG I can see all the metrics.
Can anybody help me out on this, why I'm not being able to access Prometheus on HTTP://localhost:9090 and http://localhost/-/metrics?
I couldn't spot anything wrong on the logs.

Answer (score 1):

I solve it, took me some time .

In order to access Prometheus I change this line in the gitlab.rb configuration file:
`prometheus['listen_address'] = '0.0.0.0:9090'`.

And, to access the -\metrics endpoint:
`gitlab_rails['monitoring_whitelist'] = ['127.0.0.0/8', '::1/128', '192.168.0.1', '0.0.0.0/0']`